# Win7 Senior users_Which pgRouting and postGIS versions are stable with postgreSQL8.4?

Tags: openlayers-2, postgis, geoserver, postgresql, pgrouting

I'm working on a postgreSQL ,postGIS and pgRouting project on  Windows 7

I need to work on a stable version (no time for risks), and I can see that many people are asking the same question many places..

 I think because there is not a clear instruction about the compatible and stable versions anywhere, so we (Win-pgRouting beginners) would appreciate a complete answer from senior users..

 **Here are the tools I would like to use:**

 PostgreSQL 8.4 

postGIS  ??

pgRouting  ??

QGIS  ??

OpenLayers  ??

GeoServer   ??

osm2po   ??

**Here are some facts I found on during my search about stable versions compatible with pgRouting**
 
1) pgRouting on postgreSQL 9 is not a stable version (it is in beta form). postgis.net/windows_downloads 

  2) Expert users confirming that version 8 is used by most of them who are working on the collection of tools that I'm interested in 
rndxpress.wordpress.com/2012/07/11/…


3)Problems with the new version collections gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26816/… 


4)This is a pgRouting4Windows mail list response, it is written couple of days ago it is stating explicitly by the Win pgRouting binaries' developers that it does not work properly with PostgreSQL 9 and they are at this moment forming a group of developers who are willing to build a stable version pledgebank.com/pgRoutingWindows

**THE QUESTION:**

From your experience using this collection of tools, what versions do you suggest that I should use?
I installed postgreSQL8.4,  but I’m not sure which compatible versions I should install for postGIS and pgRouting
and if you have any suggestions for QGIS ,OpenLayers and osm2po,
because I'm new to the area so I'm not sure if compatibility even matters for some of those tools,


I appreciate your support, 

sara

Comment: @AndreSilva - I think she is trying to build her software suite around PGRouting, and wants to make sure the versions she chooses are compatible with it.

Comment: Your prior question strongly suggested that the real constraint was that you wanted to know what Pg, PostGIS, etc versions worked best with the current PgRouting. No?

Comment: Thanks all for your replays.
 If that helps, I'm trying to build a web-based road network map on PostgreSQL; where users can ask for the shortest path from src to dist. Then the user get it displayed along with the estimate time required to get there + if the road has an incident then the impact time is added to the estimate time to get an actual time. 
 
Dear Craig Ringer, yes you are right, this is my question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm that the following setup works for me on Win7, but I'm only running the system for experimental purposes!

PostgreSQL 8.4 with

```
select PostGIS_full_version()
"POSTGIS="1.4.2" GEOS="3.2.0-CAPI-1.6.0" PROJ="Rel. 4.6.1, 21 August 2008" USE_STATS"
```

[pgRouting-1.03_pg-8.4.2.zip](http://www.wiesenhaan.com/pgrouting/pgRouting-1.03_pg-8.4.2.zip) for Windows as listed on http://pgrouting.org/download.html

QGIS version doesn't really matter. QGIS 1.8 will do.

I've successfully adjusted the instructions at http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/geoext_client.html to work with our in-house routing webservice but haven't tried with pgRouting.

Comment: Dear underdark, thanks for answering my question, I installed them, but I did not test pgRouting yet.. thanks again..